# How to work with single file using stack?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

When I'm working with single file haskell code, without project, I can only dependent on the `base` package and import it's modules, but when I want to import modules from other packages, I have to create a new project and edit it's `package.yaml` and add items into `dependencies`, these works are too heavy for just a single file.

Can I put my mostly used `dependencies` list into somewhere so that when I load a single file via `stack exec -- ghci my-file.hs` it will find my imported modules correctly ?

Comment: `stack install package` does this doesn't it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Load a new package in ghci using stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39848576/load-a-new-package-in-ghci-using-stack)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few options:

- [The `--package` flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39848576/load-a-new-package-in-ghci-using-stack), for ad hoc invocations;
- [The global project](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/GUIDE/#finding-project-configs-and-the-implicit-global-project) (see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49504352/2751851)), a default configuration located at `~/.stack/global-project/stack.yaml` (or the corresponding path for your OS) which kicks in when working outside of an actual project; and
- [Stack scripts](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/GUIDE/#script-interpreter), which amount to placing a header specifying a Stack invocation atop your source file, as in this example taken from the docs...

  ```
  #!/usr/bin/env stack
  {- stack
    script
    --resolver lts-6.25
    --package turtle
    --package "stm async"
    --package http-client,http-conduit
  -}
  ```

  ... and which are useful when you want something portable.

Comment: Can I write a package.yaml and add dependencies for the global project ?

Comment: @luochen1990 That isn't possible, because the global project isn't a Cabal project (that is, something you can actually build), but just a Stack configuration. What you can do, if you want to keep track of the packages you want to keep around, is creating a normal Stack project, which will have a package.yaml (or, equivalently, a *.cabal file).

Comment: so how to use the global project to solve my problem ? is it impossible?

Comment: @luochen1990 I'm not sure why would you need a `package.yaml` while using the global project. It seems seting an appropriate resolver in (plus any non-Stackage extra-deps you might need) would be enough. (Alternatively, there is still the Stack script possibility.)

Comment: because when I run `stack exec ghc test.hs`. an error like `Could not find module 'Test.QuickCheck'` will occur. It seems that I need to add the package `QuickCheck` to somewhere like package.yaml 's dependencies.

Comment: @luochen1990 Oh, I see it now. `stack exec ghc test.hs` outside of a project will only use whatever is already installed for your global project resolver. If this is the first time you are using the *QuickCheck* package with that resolver, you need  `stack exec ghc --package QuickCheck -- test.hs`, which will install *QuickCheck* before attempting to compile your file. After you do that once, `stack exec ghc test.hs` will work (at least until you change the global project resolver).

Comment: thanks, now I can express my problem in another way: I have a list of package names, which I may depend on them when I'm working with single files, and I want the installation step to be produced automatically, when I switch the global resolver, these packages will also be automatically installed when we need to import them.

Comment: @luochen1990 I don't think there is any purpose-built way to do that. The closest you can get, I guess, is creating a brand new project with `stack new`, setting it to the same resolver as that of the global project, and then only using it to add dependencies, so that a `stack build` will install whatever you need.